# Converte String para int Arduino em C

Tags: java, c, netbeans, arduino, serial

Bom pessoal, vou tentar explicar o meu problema. Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno  software no NetBeans que se comunica com o Arduíno via Porta Serial.

O meu problema, é que no NetBeans estou enviando String, e preciso converte essa String para inteiro e não estou conseguindo. A porta Serial esta declarada como inteiro. Mas mesmo assim não recebe a String do NetBeans.

Não sei ser fui claro na pergunta, mas por favor, me ajudem.

Código do Arduino:

```
 void loop(){

     // Loop Função main  
     if(Serial.available()>0){  // Vericando se Existe conexão 

         //declarando variável que irá recebe comandos do NetBeans

          int  byteEntrada = 0; // A variável byteEntrada irá  recebe Bits do NetBeans , Esses Bits sera transforma em  comandos para o Acendimento de LEDS.
          int  Porta1 =0;    
          int  Porta2 =0;          // A variável Por1, por2,port3, Será ultizada para indicar as portas que vão  se usada no Arduino.
          int  Porta3 =0; 


             byteEntrada =  Serial.read();      // Fazendo Leitura da porta Serial  para o Comando byteEntrada
                  Porta1 =  Serial.read();     // Fazendo Leitura da porta Serial  para o Comando porta1
                  Porta2 =  Serial.read();    // Fazendo Leitura da porta Serial  para o Comando porta2
                  Porta3 =  Serial.read();  // Fazendo Leitura da porta Serial  para o Comando porta3



          if(byteEntrada == '1')
           {  // Se o Bit que veio do NetBeans for igual a 1
             Desligado(Porta1,Porta2,Porta3,'h','h','l'); // Sera passado por parametro  as portas, e a situação para cada led   se ( H )  ligado se (L) desligado.
           } 

    }
}
```

Aqui é o código do NetBeans onde está enviando:

```
public void enviarDados(String dados, String p1,String p2,String p3){
    try{
    output.write(dados.getBytes());
    output.write(p1.getBytes());
    }catch(IOException e){
        Exibir_ERRO("Erro");
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }
}
```

A função `Desligado`:

```
void  Desligado (int x,int y,int z,char st1,char st2,char st3){

    if ( st1 == 'l' ) {
        digitalWrite (x,LOW); 
     } else {
        digitalWrite (x,HIGH);
     }
    if ( st2 == 'l' ) {
       digitalWrite (y,HIGH); 
     } else {
       digitalWrite (y,HIGH);
     }
    if ( st3 == 'l' ) {
       digitalWrite (z,HIGH); 
     } else {
      digitalWrite (z,HIGH);
     }
}
```

A parte do NetBeans que esta configurando a comunicação com o Arduíno:

```
public void iniciarConexao(){
    CommPortIdentifier portaId = null;
    Enumeration portaEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while(portaEnum.hasMoreElements()){
        CommPortIdentifier atualPortaId =(CommPortIdentifier) portaEnum.nextElement();
        if(porta.equals(atualPortaId.getName())){
            portaId=atualPortaId;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(portaId == null){
        Exibir_ERRO("Não se pode conectar a porta");
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }

    try{
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portaId.open(this.getClass().getName(), timeOut);
        //parametros da porta serial

        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(dataRate, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Exibir_ERRO(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }
}

public void enviarDados(String dados,String p1,String p2,String p3){
    try{
    output.write(dados.getBytes());
    output.write(p1.getBytes());
    output.write(p2.getBytes());
    output.write(p3.getBytes());

    }catch(IOException e){
        Exibir_ERRO("Erro");
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Jefferson. Apenas pelo código e descrição da sua pergunta não está muito claro o que você está tentando fazer e qual o problema que está enfrentando. O que é `output`? Essa é a `OutputStream` da porta? Como a `SerialPort` está configurada do lado do java? Onde você está fazendo a leitura da String do lado do C? Talvez [esse exemplo do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502517/send-string-from-java-to-arduino-simple-example) esclareça algumas coisas.

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo dessas strings que você está tentando enviar? Porque que o método de envio utiliza os parâmetros `dados` e `p1`, mas não utiliza o `p2` e o `p3`?

Comment: desculpe se não fui claro na minha pergunta , esse output Seria pra enviar pro Arduino, @Anthony Accioly **    
    public void iniciarConexao(){
        CommPortIdentifier portaId = null;
        Enumeration portaEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        
        while(portaEnum.hasMoreElements()){
            CommPortIdentifier atualPortaId =(CommPortIdentifier) portaEnum.nextElement();
            if(porta.equals(atualPortaId.getName())){
                portaId=atualPortaId;
                break;
            }
        }
 **

Comment: @VictorStafusa   estou tentando enviar os seguintes comando , O dado é referente do comando se ligar ou apagar a LED, já p1, p2,p3, é configurando qual pino sera ligado.

Comment: @JeffersonSantos Edite a pergunta para ficar mais claro. Não entendi as strings, quais são os possíveis conteúdos de cada string? Me parece que essas strings deveriam ser `boolean`s.

Comment: Coloque o código da função `Desligado` do arduino também.

Comment: @VictorStafusa alterei a pergunta num sei se agora ta mas clara

Comment: @JeffersonSantos Já tenho uma resposta pela metade, mas ainda falta uma coisa para que eu possa terminá-la: Quem é que está chamando o método `enviarDados`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira coisa que eu vejo de errado é na sua função `Desligado`:

```c
void  Desligado (int x,int y,int z,char st1,char st2,char st3){

    if ( st1 == 'l' ) {
        digitalWrite (x,LOW); 
     } else {
        digitalWrite (x,HIGH);
     }
    if ( st2 == 'l' ) {
       digitalWrite (y,HIGH); 
     } else {
       digitalWrite (y,HIGH);
     }
    if ( st3 == 'l' ) {
       digitalWrite (z,HIGH); 
     } else {
      digitalWrite (z,HIGH);
     }
}
```

Observe o segundo `if-else`: Se o `st2` for igual a `l` então ele coloca `HIGH` no `y`. Senão, ele também coloca `HIGH` igualmente do mesmo jeito! Acho que tinha que ser `LOW` e `HIGH` ao invés de `HIGH` e `HIGH`. O mesmo vale para o terceiro `if-else`.

Assim sendo, o seu código ficaria assim:

```c
void Desligado(int x, int y, int z, char st1, char st2, char st3) {
    if (st1 == 'l') {
        digitalWrite(x, LOW); 
    } else {
        digitalWrite(x, HIGH);
    }
    if (st2 == 'l') {
        digitalWrite(y, LOW); 
    } else {
        digitalWrite(y, HIGH);
    }
    if (st3 == 'l') {
        digitalWrite(z, LOW);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(z, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Entretanto, ainda daria para simplificar ainda mais graças ao operador ternário:

```c
void Desligado(int x, int y, int z, char st1, char st2, char st3) {
    digitalWrite(x, st1 == 'l' ? LOW : HIGH);
    digitalWrite(y, st2 == 'l' ? LOW : HIGH);
    digitalWrite(z, st3 == 'l' ? LOW : HIGH);
}
```

Por outro lado, na verdade não precisamos do operador ternário. Ele está sendo usado para traduzir de char para as constantes `LOW` ou `HIGH`. Se passarmos como parâmetro as próprias contantes, eliminamos a necessidade de se ter o operador ternário:

```c
void Desligado(int x, int y, int z, int st1, int st2, int st3) {
    digitalWrite(x, st1);
    digitalWrite(y, st2);
    digitalWrite(z, st3);
}
```

E do lado de fora ao invés disso:

```c
Desligado(Porta1,Porta2,Porta3,'h','h','l');
```

Passamos a ter isso:

```c
Desligado(Porta1, Porta2, Porta3, HIGH, HIGH, LOW);
```

Entretanto, essa função está apenas associando três portas a três níveis lógicos de forma direta e independente. Ou seja, ela não está encapsulando nenhuma lógica complexa e não está contribuindo muito com a simplicidade do código. Logo, podemos eliminá-la e então a função `loop` fica assim (tirei os comentários):

```c
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int byteEntrada = 0;
        int Porta1 = 0;
        int Porta2 = 0;
        int Porta3 = 0;
        byteEntrada = Serial.read();
        Porta1 = Serial.read();
        Porta2 = Serial.read();
        Porta3 = Serial.read();

        if (byteEntrada == '1') {
            digitalWrite(Porta1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(Porta2, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(Porta3, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Dá para simplificar a função loop ao ver que os valores zeros usados na inicialização nunca são usados, e portanto podem ser eliminados:

```c
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int byteEntrada = Serial.read();
        int Porta1 = Serial.read();
        int Porta2 = Serial.read();
        int Porta3 = Serial.read();

        if (byteEntrada == '1') {
            digitalWrite(Porta1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(Porta2, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(Porta3, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Dá para simplificar mais um pouco ao perceber-se que se o fluxo não entrar no `if`, então a função chegará ao final sem fazer mais nada (e com isso podemos tomar um atalho):

```c
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() <= 0) return;
    int byteEntrada = Serial.read();
    int Porta1 = Serial.read();
    int Porta2 = Serial.read();
    int Porta3 = Serial.read();

    if (byteEntrada != '1') return;
    digitalWrite(Porta1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Porta2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Porta3, LOW);
}
```

Bem, quanto ao "lado do Netbeans", isso não existe. O correto seria dizer "lado do Java". Quem executa isso é o Java, e não o NetBeans. O NetBeans é apenas um editor de texto anabolizado, não é ele quem extá executando os seus programas de verdade. O que acontece é que o NetBeans te dá uns botõeszinhos para executar o programa, mas tudo que ele faz na verdade por debaixo dos panos é pedir para o sistema operacional executar a JVM e pedir para a JVM executar o seu programa. Isso é mais ou menos o mesmo que pedir para o seu sobrinho ligar o ventilador da sala, quem vai te dar o vento é o ventilador e não o seu sobrinho, o sobrinho apenas ligou ele.

Bem, vamos ver no lado do Java:

```java
public void enviarDados(String dados,String p1,String p2,String p3){
    try{
    output.write(dados.getBytes());
    output.write(p1.getBytes());
    output.write(p2.getBytes());
    output.write(p3.getBytes());

    }catch(IOException e){
        Exibir_ERRO("Erro");
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }
}
```

Isso não vai fazer o que você quer. O que você quer é enviar os bytes 1, 2, 3, e não as strings "1", "2", "3". Isso é bastante diferente porque [o caractere "1" é codificado com o byte 49, o caractere "2" é codificado com o byte 50 e o "3" com o 51](http://ic.unicamp.br/~everton/aulas/hardware/tabelaASCII.pdf). Assim sendo, precisamos fazer a conversão no Java.

Não sei onde é que você usa a função `enviarDados`, mas vamos supor que você queira usá-la assim:

```java
enviarDados(1, 3, 4, 5);
```

Então, você teria que usar o tipo `int` ao invés de `String`:

```java
public void enviarDados(int dados, int p1, int p2, int p3) {
    try {
        output.write((byte) dados);
        output.write((byte) p1);
        output.write((byte) p2);
        output.write((byte) p3);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Exibir_Erro("Erro");
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }
}
```

Mas se você quiser usar assim:

```java
enviarDados("1", "3", "4", "5");
```

Então, você teria que fazer assim:

```java
public void enviarDados(String dados, String p1, String p2, String p3) {
    try {
        output.write(Byte.parseByte(dados));
        output.write(Byte.parseByte(p1));
        output.write(Byte.parseByte(p2));
        output.write(Byte.parseByte(p3));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Exibir_Erro("Erro");
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }
}
```

Ou então, se você já tiver ele em bytes:

```java
byte a = ..., b = ..., c = ..., d = ...;
enviarDados(a, b, c, d);
```

Então, você não precisaria de conversão nenhuma:

```java
public void enviarDados(byte dados, byte p1, byte p2, byte p3) {
    try {
        output.write(dados);
        output.write(p1);
        output.write(p2);
        output.write(p3);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Exibir_Erro("Erro");
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }
}
```

Dá para separar a localização da porta serial da abertura em dois métodos separados. A única coisa chata é que a API [`javax.comm`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/) esteja tão parada no tempo que até hoje não ofereá o *generics* do Java 5 (que já é bem velhinho com seus 12 anos):

```java
private CommPortIdentifier localizarPortaSerial() {
    CommPortIdentifier portaId = null;
    List<CommPortIdentifier> portas = Collections.list((Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier>) CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers());

    for (CommPortIdentifier portaId : portas) {
        if (porta.equals(portaId.getName())) return portaId;
    }
    Exibir_ERRO("Não se pode conectar a porta");
    System.exit(ERROR);
    throw new AssertionError(); // Nunca será executado por causa do System.exit.
}

public void iniciarConexao() {
    CommPortIdentifier portaId = localizarPortaSerial();

    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portaId.open(this.getClass().getName(), timeOut);
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(dataRate, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Exibir_ERRO(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(ERROR);
    }
}
```

Deve haver mais um monte de melhorias possíveis, mas para isso eu precisaria conhecer mais detalhes da classe que tem os métodos `iniciarConexao()` e `enviarDados()` e o campo `porta`. Em especial, usar `System.exit` é uma péssima prática de programação - nunca use isso - mas sem ver o resto da classe, não tenho como te dizer de que forma você poderia eliminá-lo.

Comment: Em primeiro Lugar Quero agradece por te respondido com tanta clareza minha duvida,  não me ajudo apenas no meu problema mas em varias coisas que tinha duvidas, de coração muito obrigado de verdade, sou iniciante no mundo da programação mas quando eu tiver conhecimento  prometo ajuda o próximo igual você fez comigo. Obg mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Não importa o tipo de variável que metes do lado do NetBeans porque é "convertido" para comunicação série.

Segundo o que percebi, tu queres ler inteiros de uma string enviada pelo NetBeans.
Vou utilizar um caso próprio como exemplo. Eu enviava 3 valores inteiros pela porta série e lia da seguinte forma:

```
int t1=0, t2=90, t3=0;
String a;
a=Serial.readString();
sscanf(a,"%d %d %d",&t1,&t2,&t3);
```

Ajudou?

Comment: Mt obg por ajuda mas não deu muito certo não , me retorno esse ERRO, exit status 1 cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int sscanf(const char*, const char*, ...)', dando erro na linha  sscanf(a,"%d %d %d",&t1,&t2,&t3); ,   quero passa por parametro essas porta lida da porta serial , porta1 porta2 porta3 , só que ele não conseguir converte em in , Por exemplo     Desligado(Porta1,Porta2,Porta3,'h','h','l');   ,Seria   Desligado(1,2,3,'h','h','l');  assim da certo eu coloca numero,  mas queria ultilizar   Desligado(Porta1,Porta2,Porta3,'h','h','l');  , DEU PRA ENTENDER?